# How to delete row(s) in the ag-grid with server-side rows model?

Tags: typescript, ngrx, ag-grid

I've set up ag-grid with server-side row model with pagination and want to remove row(s) by clicking a button on the row.

The code to delete is called inside of column definition, so it have access to the params: ValueGetterParams and to the params.api: GridApi

**What is best way to delete row(s) with server-side row model?**

I expect that the flow should be like following:

1. send delete request to the backend

2.1. [error state] -> do nothing (notify user)

2.2. [success state] -> params.api.?refreshServerSideCurrentPage()?

3. ag-grid calls getRows on the datasource with same startRow and endRow to fully fill the page and the successCallback is used when rows are ready.

or, knowing what rows was successfully deleted, the flow can looks like following:

...

2.2. [success state] -> params.api.?removeServerSideRows?(rowIds | rows_to_delete)

3. ag-grid calls getRows on the datasource with startRow and endRow to fill the rest of the page (or rest of this page plus following by them cache) and the successCallback is used when rows are ready.

Currently, I found that the api.paginationGoToPage method does page refresh (but only if switch to another page and then switch back)

The api.purgeServerSideCache resets current page to the first page. So, it refreshes, but too hardly. :)

Also I found api.removeFromEnterpriseCache/api.addToEnterpriseCache methods that are commented in the ag-grid repo in order of 'AG-1569 - further row model renaming' commit.

Probably these methods did what it needs from deletion?

Does the ag-grid team have plan to rename and return them or there are better way to do deletion/addition?

Comment: I am not able to find method `api.refreshServerSideCurrentPage` OR `api.removeServerSideRows` on documentation https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api/. Which version are you using?

Comment: I just wrap it (and ?removeServerSideRows?) into question marks as pseudocode, because I didn't find something like that too and gues that it should be something like that.

Comment: Anyway, I investigated more and found following: two methods was commented out in order of the 'AG-1569 - further row model renaming' repository commit. They are: ```public removeFromEnterpriseCache(route: string[], items: any[]): void``` and ```public addToEnterpriseCache(route: string[], items: any[], index: number): void```. And no replacement is found by me.

Comment: Current workaround can be: to cast api to unknown type to have access to the private serverSideRowModel field and call it's removeFromCache method. This is what commented methods did. I tried and found that it works as expected - as I described in the question.

Comment: Something like that:

```interface ServerSideRowModelFix {
    removeFromCache: (route: string[], items: any[]) => void;
}

interface GridApiFix {
    serverSideRowModel: ServerSideRowModelFix;
}
/// in the click, params.api is GridApi type
(<GridApiFix>(<unknown>params.api)).serverSideRowModel.removeFromCache(null, [params.api.getRowNode((<MyOwnDataTypeItemForRow>params.data).id)]);
```